# Webscraping Selenium and PhantomJS Returning text for product details

Tags: python, html, selenium, phantomjs, headless

I'm a noob in webscraping with python, I'm trying to retrieve the product details text of a webpage using Selenium and phantomJS, because this page does not show the rendered html when I use the  "driver.page_source", my code is this one:

```
url = 'https://www.jumbo.cl/frutas-y-verduras?page=1'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
```

Unfornately, doing this I retrieve the same source code without visualize the rendered format

Extract of the code that I return:

```
categoryId\\":\\"21\\",\\"productTitle\\":\\"Champiñón 200 g | Jumbo.cl\\",\\"metaTagDescription\\":\\"Encuentra Champiñón 200 g y la mejor variedad de Verduras en Jumbo.cl\\",\\"releaseDate\\":\\"2017-08-24T00:00:00\\",\\"clusterHighlights\\":{\\"325\\":\\"Dia de la fruta y verdura\\",\\"3554\\":\\"Vitrina 3554 limpia\\",\\"3862\\":\\"EXCLUSIVO 31082019\\",\\"3864\\":\\"DESPACHO 310819\\"
```

Extract of the  goal code ( I can visualize this code into the chrome console, but when I access to the source code, the page returns me the code above).

```
<li class="shelf-item">
  <div class="shelf-product-island">
```

The container with the  details values  for each product is inside the list of class "shelf-item"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chromedriver instead of PhantomJS() and code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

def parse(url):
    driver.get(url)

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    title_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="shelf-product-title"]/h2')

    title_list_text = [t.get_attribute('textContent') for t in title_list]

    return title_list_text

titles_list = parse("https://www.jumbo.cl/frutas-y-verduras?page=1")

print(titles_list)
```

but be aware if you want to parse second and others page then you have to pass second page url to the function like:

```
titles_list = parse("https://www.jumbo.cl/frutas-y-verduras?page=2")
```

And so on. Or find a pager button in the bottom of the page, click on it and reparse another page

Comment: thanks!  I didn't know about get_attribute. now I could take the text required